# Debezium before field is null for update operation

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

My Debezium is run by server ,and my config file is below

```
debezium.sink.type=kafka
debezium.source.connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
debezium.source.offset.storage.file.filename=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore
debezium.source.offset.flush.interval.ms=0
debezium.source.database.hostname=localhost
debezium.source.database.port=5432
debezium.source.plugin.name=pgoutput
debezium.source.database.user=casdoor
debezium.source.database.password=casdoor
debezium.source.database.dbname=casdoor
debezium.source.database.server.name=casdoor
debezium.source.database.schema.name=public
debezium.source.database.table.name=user


debezium.source.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
debezium.source.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

debezium.sink.kafka.producer.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
debezium.sink.kafka.producer.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
quarkus.log.console.json=false
```

but the update data in kafka have no before part.

[kafka data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJh1H.png)

as shown in the picture,the before is always null. but the operation is update data

```
{
    "schema":Object{...},
    "payload":{
        "before":null,
        "after":Object{...},
        "source":Object{...},
        "op":"u",
        "ts_ms":1652168353005,
        "transaction":null
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check what is the `REPLICA IDENTITY` on the table?

Comment: can you tell me where to config this, in the postgreql table or at the Debezium config file? can you give me a example?

Comment: thank you for you help

I have config the table's replica identity is full. but the before field include all field

i just want to get the field is just change

can you help me how to config？